# smart css div positioning

Tags: html, css, layout

I am wondering what the smartest way to position my divs is. I am trying to place the divs as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------|
|               |                          |  div2       |
|    div1       |                          |_____________|
|               |                                        |
|               |                           _____________|
|               |                          |  div3       |
|_______________|__________________________|_____________|
|                                                        |
|                     div4                               |
|________________________________________________________|
```

the idea of the different divs is:

- div1: a logo
- div2: some links
- div3: search field
- div4: a menu

So how whould you guys do this? I have already made it myself, but I am sure that my solution is far from perfect, so I hope that some of you have some great solutions.

You dont have to give a full code or anything, just hints on how this "should" be done.

Thanks in advance :)

Btw I made a jsfiddle with my "solution": http://jsfiddle.net/3wwaw/

Comment: The only criteria is: does it work in all browsers? If your solution works in all browsers than most other points are going to be subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on it (some css omitted for clarity)

http://jsfiddle.net/3wwaw/1/

```
<div class='topContainer'>
    <div class='topFieldLeft'>LOGO</div>
    <div class='topFieldRight'>SEARCH</div>
</div>
<div class='topmenu'>menu</div>
<div class='contentContainer'></div>

div.topContainer {
    height:50px
}

div.topFieldLeft {
    float: left;
}

div.topFieldRight {
    float: right;
}

div.topmenu {
    width:100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.50;
    filter: alpha(opacity 50);
    clear: both;
}

div.contentContainer {
    max-width: 900px;
    min-width: 600px;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin: 40px auto auto auto;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: How would you do if you wanted the containers to be centered? Also how could the div2 & div3 be placed(from my sketch on my post) ?

Comment: well, I figured it out and I think everything is placed as it should. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: center the container with margin: 0 auto; The auto will make the left and right margins whatever they need to be to center your container

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `position:absolute;` is not really needed in this case. Use the css `float` property.

I adjusted the CSS code to reflect this and cleared the floats by applying `clear:both;` on the container.

Also *please* note: this `margin: 0 auto 0 auto;` is the same as `margin: 0 auto;`. Which without values, means margin: top/bottom & left/right. Instead of margin: top right bottom left.

See my jsFiddle to play around with it and see what I did. Very basic changes.
http://jsfiddle.net/3wwaw/3/

> ***FLOAT DEFINITION:***
>  The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the
>   left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements
>   will wrap around it. A floating element is one where the computed
>   value of float is not none.

More information on floats can be found here, including use cases:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0):

I find that the "best" way to position things depends mostly on two things:

1. How much do I know about the size of the things I'm positioning (fixed in px?  fixed in em but with a variable font-size? totally variable?)?  These questions apply to both height and width.
2. What do I want to happen when the containers are bigger or smaller than they need to be (including the container that is the browser window itself)?  For example, where does extra space get allocated if the container is really big?  If the container is really small, is it ok for content to overlap other content or do I need to force scroll bars by setting min-height/width?

You didn't specify either of these things, so I'd have to make a bunch of assumptions to even begin to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-1 row-fluid">
         <div class="span3" id="div1" />
         <div class="span6" />
         <div class="span3">
            <div class="height-33" id="div2" />
            <div class="height-33">
            <div class="height-33" id="div3" />
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-2" id="div4" />
</div>
```

The height-33 is just a crude class to mention that height is 33%. Note that for % to work, we need to fix the parent's height. Use bootstrap's or similar span3 percentages to split it. Always maintains a site's structure well.